# Impact of deleting VLAN over Port Admin/oper status?

Tags: port, vlan

Is there any use case where deleting a VLAN causes an interface's admin/oper status changed?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible for the switch to drop ALL remote connections while it applies the settings. Of course it will happen if you apply a VLAN, but also removing a VLAN has been known to do this.